# trying to find a way to "listen" to events on an external web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Im trying to find a way to listen to changes that accoure on a random page, for example lets say im trying to listen on a stock price located in a website that dosnt have an api for pulling that data.
Currently what im doing is reading the page each couple of seconds and parse that specific element with jquery, which is hacki's in my opinion.
Is there away to listen to the event that changes the stock price? or anything better?

Comment: What you are doing is the way to do it. The technique is not hackish though parsing html to get data certainly is. This technique of fetching data again and again is called polling and it is how protocols like USB work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://socket.io/.

So if any changes done in page, you can emit & listen it on another page, so you will know that change has been made.

Ex. Suppose you are in page1 & you made some changes & that changes you want to get in page 2. Then from page 1 emit it & in page 2 you can listen it.

Comment: In this case page1 is owned by a 3rd party, like Google or Spotify or NYSE. How on earth are you going to install socket.io on Google's web page?